# Crystal Report without a table

Tags: c#, ado.net, crystal-reports, dataset

I am wondering if there is a way to add data to crystal report without the use of any table.
I have few text boxes in my Win Forms Application and I want to dynamicaly populate the Report(refreshing it) with the values from the text boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using `parameterfields`.

Please refer following links

[Working with Parameter Fields in Crystal Reports](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/john_charles/working-with-parameter-fields-in-crystal-reports/)

[How to pass discrete parameters to Crystal Reports](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9263/How-to-pass-discrete-parameters-to-Crystal-Reports)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by
1-create your report with any database or dataset in your project
2-after you complete design of report
  in run time you can build dataset and put a table in it with fields as report desgin
3-fill it by data from textboxes 
4-set datasource of reposrt to dataset
  and show report